# Why can't send hotkey Ctrl?

Tags: vba

If send hotkey simple. It is OK:

```
Shell "Notepad", vbNormalFocus
 SendKeys "P"
```

But if send hotkey has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. it not ok:

```
SendKeys "^P"
```

Why can't send hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try lowercase p

```
Shell "Notepad", vbNormalFocus
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
SendKeys "^p"
```